# Controllers to edit info throw me "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." at return view

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I have a controller to edit user pay information. So, when the controller finish its edition, it returns the same view which is charged by a controller.

This is the controller's code:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $userId)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
    $user->name = isset($request->userName) ? $request->userName : $user->name;
    $user->lastNames = isset($request->userLastNames) ? $request->userLastNames : $user->lastNames;
    $user->email = isset($request->userEmail) ? $request->userEmail : $user->email;
    $user->phoneNumber = isset($request->userPhoneNumber) ? $request->userPhoneNumber : $user->phoneNumber;
    $user->role = isset($request->userRole) ? $request->userRole : $user->role;
    $user->preferPayMethod = isset($request->preferPayMethod) ? $request->preferPayMethod : $user->preferPayMethod;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('carrito', ['user' => $userId]);
}
```

And this is the route's code:

```
Route::post('carrito/{user}', function ($userId) {
    $user = User::find($userId);
    return view('carrito')->with([
        'user' => $user
    ]);
})->name('carrito');
```

The editions works correctly but the view return throws me the header title:

`The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: You cannot redirect to a route that's defined as a POST route. All redirects are sent via GET. I don't see any necessary processing here, so changing the route to a GET should be fine

Comment: Yes, that' has worked! Thank you @aynber. I'm learning Laravel so I'm goin to ask you about if I use 'redirect', is GET the default method? Can I change it?

Comment: No. GET is the only method. That's a nature of webserver responses and redirects, not Laravel. -- Edit: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

you should use Post not Get , But the right you should use PUT for update

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There could be several possible reasons for this issue. Check for the following solutions to fix your issue

1. If you insist on using PUT you can change the form action to POST and add a hidden method_field that has a value PUTand a hidden csrf field (if you are using blade then you just need to add @csrf_field and {{ method_field('PUT') }}). This way the form would accept the request.

   ```
   <form action="..." method="POST">

   @csrf  

   @method('PUT')



   </form>
   ```
2. The other possible reason is routing cache in Laravel, so clear the cache by running the artisan code.

   ```
    php artisan route:cache
   ```
3. There is another method that can work as magic (This had worked for me also when I encountered this issue)

   ```
    php artisan route:clear
   ```

Note: All these possible solutions may work in both cases either GET not working or POST not working. (Do changes accordingly). Hope this solves your problem